# How to select and highlight a window in another application?

Tags: c++, windows

I would like to send some keystrokes from a C++ program into another window.

For that reason I would like to have the user select the target window similar to how it is done in the Spy++ utility that comes with Visual Studio (drag a crosshair cursor over target window and have target window highlighted by a frame).

How is this dragging and selecting done in Windows? I am completely lost as to where I might start to look for a mechanism to implement this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it's usually done:

1. Capture the mouse using [SetCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262.aspx). This will cause all mouse messages to be routed toward your app's window.
2. Handle the [WM_MOUSEMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645616.aspx) message. In your handler code, grab the window underneath the mouse using [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558.aspx). That will get you the HWND of the window the mouse is currently over.
3. Now that you've got the window, you need a device context (HDC). You can get one using [GetWindowDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534830.aspx) for the specified window.
4. Now you can draw into the DC using typical GDI functions.

There are some things you have to look out for - cleanly erasing the selection rectangle and so forth, but that's one way to do it.

You could also draw into a screen DC to do this, but in any case you'll need the window handle in order to get the window rect.

If you Google around Spy++ source code you'll see a few examples of this technique.

Comment: Problem with this approach is that DWM (in particular Aero) doesn't know about your nicely drawn images and obliterates them at random.

Answer (score 0):

Formers answers are wrong.

Spy++ source code has been given on G. Groups for years (see mainly Win32 api ng news://194.177.96.26/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32)

Comment: I'm familiar with the Spy++ code, but there's more than one way to do this. You can do it out of process, using the technique described above, or you can do it in-process, using hooks, DLL injection, and subclassing. Which I believe is what Spy++ does. But it's not strictly necessary for painting.